# Map memory to another address

Tags: c, memory

X86-64, Linux, Windows.

Consider that I'd want to make some sort of "free launch for tag pointers". Basically I want to have two pointers that point to the same actual memory block but whose bits are different. (For example I want one bit to be used by GC collection or for some other reason).

```
intptr_t ptr = malloc() 
intptr_t ptr2 = map(ptr | GC_FLAG_REACHABLE) //some magic call

int* p = int*(ptr);
int* p2 = int*(ptr2);
*p = 10;
*p2 = 20;
assert(*p == 20)
assert(p != p2)
```

Answer (score 2):

On Linux, mmap() the same file twice. Same thing on Windows really, but it has its own set of functions for that.

Answer (score 2):

Mapping the same memory (`mmap` on POSIX as Ignacio mentions, `MapViewOfFile` on Windows) to multiple virtual addresses may provide you some interesting coherency puzzles (are writes at one address visible when read at another address?).  Or maybe not.  I'm not sure what all the platform guarantees are.

More commonly, one simply reserves a few bits in the pointer and shifts things around as necessary.

If all your objects are aligned to 8-byte boundaries, it's common to simply store tags in the 3 least-significant bits of a pointer, and mask them off before dereferencing (as thkala mentions).  If you choose a higher alignment, such as 16-bytes or 32-bytes, then there are 3 or 5 least-significant bits that can be used for tagging.  Equivalently, choose a few most-significant bits for tagging, and shift them off before dereferencing.  (Sometimes non-contiguous bits are used, for example when packing pointers into the signalling NaNs of IEEE-754 floats (2<sup>23</sup> values) or doubles (2<sup>51</sup> values).)

Continuing on the high end of the pointer, current implementations of x86-64 use at most 48 bits out of a 64-bit pointer (0x0000000000000000-0x00007fffffffffff + 0xffff800000000000-0xffffffffffffffff) and Linux and Windows only hand out addresses in the first range to userspace, leaving 17 most-significant bits that can be safely masked off.  (This is neither portable nor guaranteed to remain true in the future, though.)

Another approach is to stop considering "pointers" and simply use indices into a larger memory array, as the JVM does with [`-XX:+UseCompressedOops`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html#compressedOop).  If you've allocated a 512MB pool and are storing 8-byte aligned objects, there are 2<sup>26</sup> possible object locations, so a 32-value has 6 bits to spare in addition to the index.  A dereference will require adding the index times the alignment to the base address of the array, saved elsewhere (it's the same for every "pointer").  If you look at things carefully, this is simply a generalization of the previous technique (which always has base at 0, where things line up with real pointers).

Answer (score 1):

Once upon a time I worked on a Prolog implementation that used the following technique to have spare bits in a pointer:

- Allocate a memory area with a known alignment. `malloc()` usually allocates memory with a 4-byte or 8-byte alignment. If necessary, use [`posix_memalign()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memalign) to get areas with a higher alignment size.
- Since the resulting pointer is aligned to intervals of multiple bytes, but it represents byte-accurate addresses, you have a few spare bits that will by definition be zero in the memory area pointer. For example a 4-byte alignment gives you two spare bits on the LSB side of the pointer.
- You OR (`|`) your flags with those bits and now have a tagged pointer.
- As long as you take care to properly mask the pointer before using it for memory access, you should be perfectly fine.